# Show that for any non-zero vectors $v_1, v_2, ... v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a hyperplane which does not contain any of them.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is how far I got:

Let $\mathbb{B} = \{e_1, e_2, \dots e_n \}$ be the canonical basis. Then there exist real numbers $a_{i j}, i = \overline{1 \dots m}, j = \overline{1 \dots n}$ such that: $$v_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i j}e_j \text{, } \forall i \in \{1, \dots m \}$$

Let $\mathbb{B}_{H} = \{ h_1, h_2 \dots h_{n-1} \}$ be a basis of our hyperplane. We want to construct the $h_i$s such that $v_{i} \notin H$ for all $i = \overline{1 \dots m}$. I don't even know how to start constructing this basis. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider stepping into a higher-dimensional space.  Embed a plane containing all the points into a space one dimension larger, and then offset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: Here is my attempt at a slightly more intuitive reasoning. Not sure of its validity though!

When will a $v_i$ not lie on the hyperplane defined by $\mathbb{B}_H$? This happens when the projection of the vector $v_i$ onto the hyperplane is not equal to $v_i$, i.e. there is some "error" when you project it onto the hyperplane.

In other words, what you want to do is find $\mathbb{B}_H$ (a matrix with all the $h_i$ as columns) such that all $v_i$ have a non-zero component in its null space, i.e. in the orthogonal complement of the hyperplane. The orthogonal complement of a $n-1$ dimensional subspace (hyperplane) is a one dimensional subspace, and let us denote the basis of this space by a vector $b_{null}$. We therefore need to find a $b_{null}$ such that $v_i^Tb_{null} \neq 0 \forall i$

Is it always possible to find such a $b_{null}$?

#### Intuitive (visualizable in 3D)

We are picking $b_{null}$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each vector $v_i$, we eliminate several candidate $b_{null}$ which together form a hyperplane. This hyperplane is defined by the set of points perpendicular to $v_i$ (all $b_{null} \perp v_i$). Therefore, all the $v_i$ together eliminate a finite union of hyperplanes from $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since these hyperplanes are $n-1$ dimensional, we will always have points left over and we can always find $b_{null}$.

#### A little more formal

Each $v_i$ eliminates the hyperplane with $b_{null} \in S_i=\{v_j:v_j^Tv_i = 0\}$. All the candidate $b_{null}$ form $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can show that the cardinality of the set $\bigcup_iS_i$ is strictly smaller than $S$. Cardinality of each $S_i$ is that of a hyperplane, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Therefore, $\bigcup_iS_i$ has the same cardinality being a finite sum. The cardinality of $S$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which is strictly greater than $\bigcup_iS_i$. A simpler argument, as presented in the other answer is to note that a finite sum of proper subsets (each hyperplane is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We can make similar arguments if we restrict our $b_{null}$ to the unit hypersphere where all the above sets become subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ but the cardinality argument stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H_i=\langle v_i\rangle^{\perp}$ be the orthogonal complement of $v_i$ in the dual space $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$. Since $v_i$ is nonzero, $H_i$ is proper (in fact a hyperplane). But a finite-dimensional space is not a finite union of proper subspaces, so there is a linear functional $f$ not in any $H_i$. Then $\langle f\rangle^{\perp}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not containing any $v_i$.

This proof actually works for any finite-dimensional vector space over a field of characteristic $\ne 2$. But since you're working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can also just identify the dual space with the space itself via the inner product. In that case everything in the above proof happens in the same space. You can draw a diagram in the case $n=3$ with the vectors and normal planes to visualize what's going on.

Comment: do you have a proof that is more accessible to a first year math undergrad?

Comment: @Colver If you let me know which concepts you find inaccessible or unfamiliar, I can try to add another proof later if I have time.

Comment: the notion of a dual of a space. i know what it is, but we haven't introduced the theory yet so I think we're meant to use something simpler

Answer (score 0):

We may find a desired hyperplane by the following iterative algorithm. Let $V$ be the $n\times m$ matrix whose columns are the $v_j$s. We shall find a row vector $x^T$ such that $x^TV$ is entrywise nonzero.

Denote by $v_{i\ast}$ the $i$-th row of $V$. In the sequel, we will determine the elements of $x^T$ one by one. We will also construct a matrix $Y$ with the same size as $V$, so that once $x_i$ is determined, we put $y_{1\ast}=x_1v_{1\ast}$ if $i=1$ or $y_{i\ast }=y_{i-1,\ast}+x_iv_{i\ast}$ if $i\ge2$. So, at the end, we have $y_{n\ast}=x_1v_{1\ast}+x_2v_{2\ast}+\cdots+x_nv_{n\ast}=x^TV$.

Here is our construction of $x^T$ and $Y$. Set $x_1=1$ and $y_{1\ast }=v_{1\ast}$. For each $i\ge2$, if $y_{i-1,\ast}$ is the zero row vector, let $x_i=1$. Otherwise, let
$$
x_i=\frac{\min\limits_{y_{i-1,j}\ne0}|y_{i-1,j}|}{1+\|v_{i\ast}\|_\infty}.
$$
As we have mentioned previously, we also set $y_{i\ast}=y_{i-1,\ast}+x_iv_{i\ast}$. With our choice of $x_i$, we see that $y_{ij}=0$ if and only if $y_{i-1,j}=v_{ij}=0$. However, for each fixed $j$, we have $v_{i_0j}\ne0$ for some $i_0$; therefore $y_{ij}\ne0$ whenever $i\ge i_0$. In particular, $y_{nj}\ne0$ for every $j$. Hence $y_{n\ast}=x^TV$ is entrywise nonzero. That is, the dot product of $x$ with any $v_j$ is nonzero. It follows that the hyperplane orthogonal to $x$ does not contain any $v_j$.